# Get table names from a database conditionally?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database that consists of over 50000 tables. Most of the tables except for few end with hex values. So they look something like :-

```
table1_dft5678f_6e54_de54_7c54_5fd3b54cbc43
table2_dft5674f_6e54_cb54_7c55_5fd3b54ebcca
table3_dft5673f_6e54_2d54_7c53_fd23b54cbf43
```

and so on. And there are certain tables that don't end up with hex values.

```
table_name1
table_name2
```

How can i find the name of the tables that don't end up with hex values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE ...condition...
```

I'm not sure how you want to form the condition. Perhaps `LENGTH(TABLE_NAME) < 43`? Or `TABLE_NAME REGEXP '^table_name[0-9]$'`? It depends on what your real table names look like. I assume the ones you show in your question above are just artificial examples.

Comment: Hello Bill. Thanks for the reply. Yes, you're right, the names are just artificial names. I added all those letters without regards to any consideration or convention. I will try the Length option and see if that returns the right values.

Comment: This kind of works in the sense it' returning the names without hex vales but how can i look up the names in a specific database? The above query returns from all the databases. For example if the name of my database is food_detect

Comment: [If only there were some sort of documentation that describes the attributes of the information_schema tables...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html)

Comment: haha.Excellent. Got it.